# Using Windows cmd.exe and a batch .cmd, can I copy/xcopy/??? a Unicode filename from x:\* to y:\*

Tags: windows-xp, cmd.exe, unicode, filenames

I want to do a very simple thing:  Copy a file.
`Copy` is a simple (and fundamental) command. It should be easy, but it seems to be complicated when it comes to Unicode filenames (using `English XP`, `cmd.exe`, and a `.cmd` script).
I have managed to create a .cmd file with the Unicode filenames, as follows

```
    :: To create the final .cmd script
    :: 
       set SRCE=D:\_cmd\cpp
       set DEST=H%SRCE:~1%

       cmd.exe /U /c DIR /A:-D /s /b "%SRCE%" >"SRCE.UTF16" 
       cmd.exe /U /c DIR /A:-D /s /b "%DEST%" >"DEST.UTF16" 

       ConvUTF.exe  1628 "DEST.UTF16" "DEST.UTF-8"
       ConvUTF.exe  1628 "SRCE.UTF16" "SRCE.UTF-8"

    :: Then, with `sed.exe`, `diff.exe`, and `ConvUTF.exe` again...
    :: the resulting UTF-8 (or UTF16) .cmd file looks like this...
    :: 
       copy "D:\_cmd\cpp\ā.क.test" "H:\_cmd\cpp\"
```

The `copy` command works fine when I run it directly at the `command prompt`, but fails, when used in the `.cmd` script.
The UTF-8 `.cmd` errors out with: `The system cannot find the file specified`
The UTF16 `.cmd` doesn't get past the first NULL-byte (of the first character), and just exits.

Is there some way to do it from a `.cmd` script?   (I want to use the `cmd.exe` shell)
Perhaps there is a utility program which can be called from my `.cmd`...
All suggestions are welcome.

**PS**. To clarify the manin issue...  I don't care about how Unicode filenames display in the console window (That just doesn't happen for most non-latin-based letters in the cmd.exe window)...  I am only interesterd in being able to **copy** a file which has Unicode letters in its filename- **via a batch .cmd "script"**.

Comment: Can tell us what your desired output is from this?  If all you want to do is copy a file why not just us a batch file?  If you copied with a batch file all you would need to do is `xcopy c:\somefile.txt z:\somefile.txt /u /y exit`

Comment: @typoknig: Yes, `xcopy c:\somefile.txt z:\somefile.txt /u /y` works, because
your example uses filenames whose "letters" do not range beyond a single-byte char-set.  
My problem arises when I want to copy a file with Unicode characters in its filename.. by Unicode, I mean characters which have a Unicode CodePoint greater than 127 (hex 7F) .. as per my example above:   "ā.क.test"..

Comment: Very interesting question. I tried(Vista) *copy abcऊ.txt to kk\defऊ.txt* in a command window and this got pasted *copy abc?.txt to kk\def?.txt*. **Very much** interested in whats the deal with this.

Comment: @Zabba: The fact that it shows "?" is not really (necessarily) a problem.. It typically only means that the particular character `ऊ` is not known to the current console font.. However the underlying character is still `ऊ` and the copy will succeed (It does on my setup, but there may be other issues involved.  
So, I don't have a problem with that point (it is a pain! but not a show-stopper)... The issue I have is that the copy fails when the command is called from within a .cmd script..  It doesn't seem to handle any type of Unicode: UTF-8 and UTF16 both fail.. and UTF16 is native to Windows!

Comment: have you tried another copy command called robocopy?

Comment: @Shivan: I've tried "copy", "xcopy", "xxcopy", "hobocopy", and I am now looking at `robocopy.  I haven't fully tested it, but 
it seems to be the same as the rest...  Even if they accept unicode filenames via the command-line directly, they fail when the same command is applied via a batch-file. It seems to be the limitation of the batch interpreter, and not necessarily the utility programs.  I think I need something which reads a List-file rather than commandl-line args. It might be time to get the c++ compiler out or look at Pyton (perhahps).. but I'd prefer to use something pre-existing.

Comment: @orthogonal: try to re-save the batch file as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: reference link for UTF-8 encoded batch files: http://groups.google.com/group/xxcopy/browse_thread/thread/9a0a14c411b78ba1?pli=1

Comment: I'm still looking into it (but I might end up using Python after all, but even it has some issues with passing UTF-8 args to it, ie. arg from a batch .cmd)   ---- XXCOPY: 2010-01-01 http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy37.htm -- /CF (command file for regular command text) -- /EX (exclusion file; lists exclusion items)  - Currently, only a 8-bit characters are supported. ie. Unicode text is not supported, yet. ---- XXCOPY: 2009-12-23 http://www.xxcopy.com/xxtb_049.htm -- This article says that /CF and /EX are UTF-8 aware! (BOM must be present)... back to the grindstone...

Comment: @Shivan: Youv'e made the "impossible", possible! ... XXCOPY's /CF switch and associated UTF-8 List-file, does the trick.  Thanks... it isn't the "normal" passed-args method, but it certainly does the job.. and takes XXCOPY into "unlimited" realms (btw: XXCOPY is great program)

Answer (score 1):

Save the UTF-8 batch file without the BOM at the start which will trip up `cmd`. Also, `cmd` isn't really Unicode-aware when it comes to batch files. You should put

```
chcp 65001
```

into the batch at the beginning to switch to UTF-8 which *should* enable your Unicode characters to be read and processed correctly. The only downside is that this change persists even after the batch file exited and thus you're stranded with the shell in UTF-8. You can save the previous code page and restore it at the end if this poses a problem.

Also changing the console font to a TrueType font might help since several internal commands are known to exhibit Unicode problems with raster fonts (a reason why `for /f` over `dir` is such a stupid idea generally).

Comment: Thanks Joey... 
My main comuter just died. I've bought a new box.  I've installed Ubuntu...  Like the Maginot Line, I'll just go around the obstruction!
Unicode problems are now solved :)

Comment: @orth: Well, good if it works. Still, Linux or any Unix-like system has it's own share of weird Unicode problems, for example, that *everything* from the locale to the program to the terminal emulator, GNU screen SSH clients or whatever else comes between the computer and the user (yes, that may involve many levels and on some occasions many machines) has to use UTF-8, otherwise it breaks. Often it's not obvious *where* it breaks either. I think I prefer a system that supports Unicode in its core and not just as an afterthought as a quick hack.